# How to move to next ViewController on modal from left/right to right/left

Tags: ios, objective-c

In objective-C, I want to move to next ViewController on modal from left/right to right/left.
(don't use push)

How can I do screen transition on modal from left/right to right/left?

Comment: I searched how to do it on the internet, but I could find only other screen transition like flip animation and feed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do
First you need to import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

After that

```
 NextViewController *nextVC = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil]];
 CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
 [animation setDuration:0.5];
 [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
 [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
 [[nextVC.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"MoveNextView"];
 [self presentViewController:nextVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.But VC didn't appear with push animation, only appear immediately....

Comment: But in your question you asked don't use push

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "push animation" is moving left to right and right to left...

Comment: fixing my missing, I could do it! but I don't know how to dismiss modal VC from right to left. Do you know it?

Comment: Now exactly what do you want? Above my answer is helpful for you?

Comment: Now do you want to dismiss the view like above my code?

Comment: yes, I want to dismiss the view like your code.

Comment: Did you use my code?and does my code work for you?

Comment: I took a mistake on code.I did it! Thank you for answering politely.